# How to remove big PVC coupler in hot tub

Tags: plumbing, pvc, hot-tub

This PVC coupler is dripping enough to empty my hot tub in a few weeks. I can't figure out how to remove it. Do I need to cut? Or is there some way to get it off, put new sealing tape, and put it back?[image]

Comment: Looks like both ends have threaded couplings me... assuming I picked the correct thing in your picture to look at....

Comment: Talking about the thing connecting the white pipe to the metal pipe, with the grippy handles on it. Can't seem to turn it even with plenty of force.

Comment: Looks like a threaded coupling to me

Answer (score 2):

It's threaded; odds are good you don't have sufficient leverage if you're trying by hand. I'd suggest a large pair of water pump pliers, which are a fair bit more useful to have around than a large pipe wrench. You're less likely to bust anything with pliers too.

Answer (score 2):

Try a channel lock type pliers on the fitting, front center of the picture. Open the jaws so when you grip the plastic part with the serrated edges you do not squeeze or distort the plastic piece that you are trying to turn. First try to turn this part "down" which will Tighten the joint, just slightly to break the seal, then upwards to un-thread (remove) the fitting. You may have to try this up then down turn several times. If you can remove this "union fitting", you will probably find a gasket seal. You may need a new gasket or you may be able to clean up the old gasket and apply a small amount of RTV silicone to both sides of the gasket. If you do not have the correct tools or think you can not do this yourself ask someone for help or call a hot tub company to do the repair. Sometimes it is cheaper to call a professional. Last thing; I would not cut anything until I have called a professional for advice.